# Lodash orderBy alphabetical Angular Object[]

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting, multidimensional-array, lodash

I'm working on Angular 7 and I need to sort a multidimensional-array. I have a box in which my user can select a nationality. I have a `Country[]` interface with two fields inside `CountryCode` & `CountryName`.

I'd like to sort by `CountryName` and my user will be able to select a nationality in a proper alphabetical order. I saw that `Pipes` and `Lodash librairy` could help me to create a custom pipe.

Here is my actual code to get my `CountryCode` & `CountryName` from my database

```
private getCountryData() {
this.findAllCountries().subscribe((countries: Country[]) => {
this.countryList = country;
});
```

And now what I tried with Lodash

```
transform(value: Country[], by: string, direction = "asc" | "desc"): Country[] {
    this.countryList = _.orderBy(this.countryList, ['string', 'countryLabel'], ['asc', 'desc']);
    return this.countryList;
  }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `lodash`, sorting can be done using JavaScript as shown below.

```js
var countries = [
   {name: 'India', code: 'IN'},
   {name: 'France', code: 'FR'},
   {name: 'Australia', code: 'AU'},
];

var sorted = countries.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let asc = "ASC";
let desc = "DESC";
let direction = "DESC";
let countries: Country[] = [{
    CountryCode: "IN",
    CountryName: "INDIA"
  },
  {
    CountryCode: "US",
    CountryName: "UNITED STATES"
  },
  {
    CountryCode: "UK",
    CountryName: "ENGLAND"
  }
];
if (direction == "ASC") {
  countries.sort((a, b) => (a.CountryName > b.CountryName) ? 1 : -1)
} else {
  countries.sort((a, b) => (a.CountryName > b.CountryName) ? -1 : 1)
}
countries.forEach(item => {
  console.log(item.CountryName);
});
```

```
let asc ="ASC";
let desc="DESC";
let direction="DESC";
let countries: Country[] =[
  { CountryCode:"IN", CountryName:"INDIA" }, 
  {CountryCode:"US",CountryName:"UNITED STATES"}, 
  {CountryCode:"UK",CountryName:"ENGLAND"}
];

if(direction=="ASC"){
countries.sort((a, b) => (a.CountryName > b.CountryName) ? 1 : -1) 
}else {
  countries.sort((a, b) => (a.CountryName > b.CountryName) ? -1 : 1)
}

countries.forEach(item=>{
console.log(item.CountryName);
});
```

Comment: try this , let me know if you have any more questions.